# Laravel 5.0 trying to get an item from a collection "Undefined property"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a collection that looks like this:

```
Collection {#322 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    "title" => array:1 [▼
      0 => {#356 ▼
        +"id": 104
        +"block_newsletter_id": 135
        +"item_type": "title"
        +"html_key": ""
        +"content": "aze"
        +"properties": ""
      }
    ]
    "text" => array:1 [▼
      0 => {#357 ▼
        +"id": 105
        +"block_newsletter_id": 135
        +"item_type": "text"
        +"html_key": ""
        +"content": "azee"
        +"properties": ""
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

I built this collection like this:

```
collect($blockItemsContent[$block->pivot->id])->groupBy('item_type')
```

I send this collection to my view and I try to access the content of the title like this:

```
{{ $blockItemsContent->title->content }}
```

I get the following error:

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Support\Collection::$title

I also tried this:

```
{{ $blockItemsContent['title']->content }}
```

This gives me the following error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

### EDIT What I am trying in my blade

```
<td style="background-color: #ffffff;">
    <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding: 20px; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; color: #555555;">
                    <h1 style="margin: 0 0 10px; font-size: 25px; line-height: 30px; color: #0069b4; font-weight: normal;">
                        {{ $blockItemsContent->title->content }}
                    </h1>
                    <p style="margin: 0 0 10px;">
                        {{ $blockItemsContent->text->content }}
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</td>
```

Comment: Try to `dd($blockItemsContent)` before return in the controller's method. Does the collection have `title`?

Comment: try `{{ $blockItemsContent->title[0]->content }}`

Comment: Try again with foreach because it  is an array

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your application:

```
foreach ($blockItemsContent as $key=>$value){
       dd($value->content);
    }
```

Comment: but I want to display the title and text on different places in my blade that's why i group it by Item_type then i have to write multiple foreach loops?

Comment: You can loop with an foreach.

Comment: @Maryam This is not going to give you desired results

Answer (score 0):

Your collection `$blockItemsContent` is an array of objects, not the object itself. So you should access the first group via `$blockItemsContent->get("title")`. This is an array again, which you can loop with an foreach.

```
foreach($blockItemsContent->get("title") as $obj) {
  dump($obj);
}
```

Or:

```
$blockItemsContent->get("title")->each(function($obj) {
  dump($obj);
});
```

EDIT:

- Remember that `->get("title")` returns `NULL` if the key is not found
- If you don't know what values for `item_type` are possible you should
  loop over the complete collection

Comment: this also results in a Trying to get property of non-object please don't forget I am using Laravel 5.0

Comment: Isn't it possible to update your 4 years old laravel version?

Comment: Does 5.0 have the `->toArray()` or `->all()` functions in the collection? So you could get rid of the collection object after your `groupBy()` work is done

Comment: how will this help me? I am trying to avoid using multiple foreach loops can you check my edited OP?

Comment: you could access an array with `[]` and without `->get()` or whatever. Like in your edited blade it would not be possible, since you have a collection or an array. So the keys like "title" have multiple objects because of your `->groupBy()`. You posted the structure of your collection where you can see it: `"title" => array:1 [...]`. "title" is an array with 1 object in that case. That's why `..title->content` is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

That is because `$blockItemsContent` is collection which contains list of items grouped by `item_type` like you specigied in your code like this

```
collect($blockItemsContent[$block->pivot->id])->groupBy('item_type')
```

Because it's a collection you have to perform a loop before to have access to title of each item.

```
@foreach($blockItemsContent as $item_key => $item_value)

    // Notice that $item-key will contains respectively 'title' and 'text'

    {{ $item_key }} // title or text

    {{ $item_value['content'] }}

@endfor
```

Notice that `$item_value` is array, when `$item_key` to **title**,  `$item_value` will be equal to

```
$item_value = [ "id" => 105, 
    "block_newsletter_id"=> 135, 
    "item_type" => "text", 
    "html_key"=> "",
    "content"=> "azee",
    "properties" => ""
]
```

Comment: But I want to print the content of the title and the content of the text in different places in my blade this means I have to do 2 foreach loops?

Comment: yout vodes gives me Undefined index: content

Comment: No, like `$blockItemsContent` is a collection, you can access each item by targeting each item by using it `key_name` directly

Comment: I don't understand I am sorry look at my Edited OP what i am trying to achieve in my blade file

Comment: you can access `title` data like this `$cblockItemsContent->get('titlte')` notice the result is Array not Object